# How List<t> binding to JList?

Tags: java, jlist

I have Jlist. I need binding info from `List<MyType>`

Mytype

```
public class MyType {

    String _title = "";
    String _description = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your data to `JList` data model (`ListModel`).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean binding as "if I update my List the JList will also be updated and vice-versa" you are looking for something like: [Beansbinding](http://java.net/projects/beansbinding/) or [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/). If you just want to display every object of `List<MyType>` as an item in the `JList`, override `MyType` `toString` method and write some bad code such as this:

```
  List<MyType> list = ...
  JList jList = new JList(list.toArray());
```

Or implement your own [ListModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html). I would definitely advice you to go with the libraries instead of the reiventing the wheel approach.

Comment: Since I couldn't find a download link for original Beansbinding jar at java.net. Here is a link for a more active fork [BetterBeansBinding](http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home) :D

Answer (score 0):

```
//First Create Get and Set Methods
public class MyType {
    String title = "";
    String description = "";

    public String getDescription() {
        return _description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}

//Then set to List    
List<MyType> tmpList = new ArrayList<MyType>();

MyType tmpMyType = new MyType();
tmpMyType.setTitle("Maths");
tmpMyType.setDescription("Algibra");

tmpList.add(tmpMyType);
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not quite sure if I understood your question, but are you looking for:

```
JList <MyType> myList = new JList <MyType> ();
```

Comment: For JList define your own list model (probably inheriting from DefaultListModel) that handles your data type. Add a custom cell renderer (implementing ListCellRenderer) to your JList for defining how your data sets are to be displayed. This do work!